# Finding Range on which one value exist

Tags: excel

I have the following Values in Column `C:E`, the first column contains value start the second column contains end value of range and than in third column is charater

```
+-------+-----+-----------+
| Start | End | Character |
+-------+-----+-----------+
|    10 |  20 | A         |
|    25 |  45 | B         |
|    46 |     | C         |
|    47 |  90 | D         |
+-------+-----+-----------+
```

In column `A` I have the following values

```
+----+
| A  |
+----+
|  1 |
| 10 |
| 21 |
| 31 |
| 41 |
| 51 |
| 61 |
| 71 |
| 81 |
| 91 |
+----+
```

What i need is formula that can search above values are found in which range and than give the relevant character, any value that is not found in any range should not show any charater.

Thank you

Comment: What is your formula like so far? So that we can improve it where you're having a problem.

Comment: Post what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are three ranges for which you want a nil result and otherwise a standard VLOOKUP function with inexact matching should serve:

```
=IF(OR(AND(G1>20,G1<25),G1<10,G1>90),"",VLOOKUP(G1,C:E,3))
```

the value to be matched is assumed to be in G1.